# Can‘t build M2MQTT.WinRT.dll out of the M2MQTT.sln

Tags: c#, dll, mqtt, visual-studio-2019

I am facing an issue when trying to build the M2MQTT.WinRT.dll out of the M2MQTT.sln. It gives me errors saying that the namespace „Networking“ was not found in namespace „Windows“.

Since google didn‘t help, i am asking here.

Comment: Do not edit questions to include solutions (Especially don't add "FIXED" to the title, this is NOT a forum), add a proper answer and mark it as accepted. This way it will show up higher in search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved: Building the M2MQTT.WinRT.dll worked for me only in Visual Studio 2017. Building with Visual Studio 2019 did NOT work.